# Align number from enumerate with equation

Tags: equations, lists, vertical-alignment, enumerate

I'm trying to have an equation as the first line of one of my items in an `enumerate` environment.

Example:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \[ x \]
\end{enumerate}
```

[image: misaligned equation in enumerate]

I want the $x$ to have the same baseline as the 1., but it's appearing lower. How can I make the two line up properly?

Comment: then use it this way: `$x$`

Comment: I want a displayed equation that needs to be centered; using text-mode math doesn't actually help me.

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3109/displaying-an-equation-in-a-list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace{-\abovedisplayskip}%
                \[ x \]}
  \item \hfill $ x $ \hfill~
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

doesn't really make sense, from my point of view.

Comment: This actually works perfectly if you take out the `\vspace` to leave just `\parbox{\linewidth}{\[ ... \]}`. (I'm not sure why).

Comment: @Ben Alpert: If you think of a `\parbox` as a self-contained paragraph-making environment (in effect, a mini page, though not a `minipage`), you will see that the displayed equation need not start a new line at the top of one.

Comment: This actually turned out not to work as well as I thought it did; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/vertical-alignment-of-align-in-enumerate.

Comment: I assume the `hfill` for the second `\item` was to show the horizontal placement of the `x`, in which case `\item ~\hfill $ x $ \hfill~` is slightly better.  Not a big deal, but I was initially confused as to why the two `x` were not horizontally aligned.