# Vertical alignment of align* in enumerate

Tags: lists, vertical-alignment, align, enumerate

> **Related (but not the same)**:
>   [Align number from enumerate with equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9383/align-number-from-enumerate-with-equation)
>   [Displaying an equation in a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3109/displaying-an-equation-in-a-list)

Earlier today I asked a question about aligning equations in an `enumerate` environment and got an answer that seemed to work for the example I gave, but it turns out I wasn't really specific enough for my problem.

I'm using `align*` environments, often as the only part of a list item. (If you're wondering why I'm not using more words to introduce the `align*`, these are mostly homework solutions where most of the work is algebra, etc.)

Here's my code and what it makes (above the middle line):

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \begin{align*}
    x^2 + y^2 &= x^2 + (iy)^2 \\
              &= (x + iy) (x - iy)
  \end{align*}
  \item \begin{align*}
    \frac{1}{n^2-4} &= \frac14 \frac{4}{(n-2)(n+2)} \\
                    &= \frac14 \left( \frac{1}{n-2}-\frac{1}{n+2} \right)
  \end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
```

[image: sad things]

I'm trying to make the baseline of the first line of the `align*` environment the same as the number's baseline—I want the first line of the `align*` to have the same vertical position (centered horizontally in the same way) relative to its number as in the second half of my picture. (Side question: why is there so much space before the `align*` starts?)

Comment: +1 for explaining that this is about homework solutions. (By the way, it should be `x^2 - (iy)^2` in the first line; I corrected that in my answer.)

Comment: Right, sorry. Just goes to show why I shouldn't type without thinking.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I had been using Philippe Goutet's solution posted here, but have fairly recently found a simpler solution of using the `aligned` environment with the optional `[t]` alignment:

```
  \item $\begin{aligned}[t]
    x^2 + y^2 &= x^2 + (iy)^2 \\
              &= (x + iy) (x - iy)
  \end{aligned}$
```

which yields:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe) was used to show the page margins.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item $\begin{aligned}[t]
    x^2 + y^2 &= x^2 + (iy)^2 \\
              &= (x + iy) (x - iy)
  \end{aligned}$
  \item $\begin{aligned}[t]
    \frac{1}{n^2-4} &= \frac14 \frac{4}{(n-2)(n+2)} \\
                    &= \frac14 \left( \frac{1}{n-2}-\frac{1}{n+2} \right)
  \end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want them horizontally centered as is the default with the `align` environment you could add an `\hfill` on either side:

```
  \item \hfill$\begin{aligned}[t]
    x^2 + y^2 &= x^2 + (iy)^2 \\
              &= (x + iy) (x - iy)
  \end{aligned}$\hfill\null
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \hfill$\begin{aligned}[t]
    x^2 + y^2 &= x^2 + (iy)^2 \\
              &= (x + iy) (x - iy)
  \end{aligned}$\hfill\null
  \item \hfill$\begin{aligned}[t]
    \frac{1}{n^2-4} &= \frac14 \frac{4}{(n-2)(n+2)} \\
                    &= \frac14 \left( \frac{1}{n-2}-\frac{1}{n+2} \right)
  \end{aligned}$\hfill\null
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great! Somehow I had decided previously that the fractions wouldn't line up right, but it appears that they do.

Comment: Nice! One caveat, though: it you want to embed the formula(e) in a sentence, everything that comes after the `aligned` (say, a comma) is *also* top aligned. Such connectives can go inside the environment, though.

Comment: The solution with `aligned` in an inline equation is simple, but it will not work if the equation must be numbered. It seems that the solution proposed here by Philippe Goutet is the only one that (1) is automatically aligned, whatever the height of the first line, contrary to solutions with `\parbox{\linewidth}{\[...\]}`; (2) works in an `\item` (which is nice if the equation is followed by some explanation in the `\item`, such as "where $x$ is..."), contrary to solutions where the bullet in inserted in the equation; (3) works for numbered equations.

Answer (score 13):

There is a way to automatically measure the space between the beginning of the `\item` and the first line of the `{align*}` with the pdftex primitive `\pdfsavepos`. The `savepos` option of the [zref package](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref) allows a rather nice interface for this feature.

The code works like this: you place a `\mi` macro where you want the material to be and you place a `\md` (you can change these names if you don't like them) where the material is. For example,

```
  \item \mi\begin{align*}\md
      x^2 + y^2 &= x^2 + (iy)^2 \\
              &= (x + iy) (x - iy)
  \end{align*}
```

After a few compilation (up to 4 may be needed), you will obtain perfect alignment of the equation and the item number.

Here's the full code, showing how the alignment works with a few equations and a table. I've also put a variant in which I redefined `{align*}` so that `\mi` and `\md` are not necessary anymore (making it easier to type).

[image: result of the code]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{autoenumvspace}
\setcounter{autoenumvspace}{0}
\newcommand{\mi}{\markitemstart}
\newcommand{\markitemstart}{%
  \addtocounter{autoenumvspace}{1}%
  \@ifundefined{autoenumvspacevalue\romannumeral\value{autoenumvspace}}%
    {\edef\autoenumvspace@value{0pt}}%
    {\edef\autoenumvspace@value{\csname autoenumvspacevalue\romannumeral\value{autoenumvspace}\endcsname}%
  }
  \ifnum\zposy{auto@enum@\number\value{autoenumvspace}@bottom}=%
        \zposy{auto@enum@\number\value{autoenumvspace}@top}
     \@ifundefined{autoenumvspacevalue\romannumeral\value{autoenumvspace}}%
     {}%
     {\immediate\write\@mainaux{\gdef\expandafter\noexpand\csname autoenumvspacevalue\romannumeral\value{autoenumvspace}\endcsname{\csname autoenumvspacevalue\romannumeral\value{autoenumvspace}\endcsname}}}%
  \else
     \ifdim\dimexpr\zposy{auto@enum@\number\value{autoenumvspace}@bottom}sp-\zposy{auto@enum@\number\value{autoenumvspace}@top}sp\relax=\autoenumvspace@value
        \immediate\write\@mainaux{\gdef\expandafter\noexpand\csname autoenumvspacevalue\romannumeral\value{autoenumvspace}\endcsname{\the\dimexpr\zposy{auto@enum@\number\value{autoenumvspace}@bottom}sp-\zposy{auto@enum@\number\value{autoenumvspace}@top}sp\relax}}%
     \else
        \edef\autoenumvspace@value{0pt}%
        \immediate\write\@mainaux{\gdef\expandafter\noexpand\csname autoenumvspacevalue\romannumeral\value{autoenumvspace}\endcsname{\the\dimexpr\zposy{auto@enum@\number\value{autoenumvspace}@bottom}sp-\zposy{auto@enum@\number\value{autoenumvspace}@top}sp\relax}}%
     \fi
  \fi
  \vspace*{-\autoenumvspace@value}%
  \leavevmode
  \zsavepos{auto@enum@\number\value{autoenumvspace}@top}%
  \vspace*{\autoenumvspace@value}%
}
\newcommand{\md}{\markdisplaystart}
\newcommand{\markdisplaystart}{%
  \zsavepos{auto@enum@\number\value{autoenumvspace}@bottom}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Manual version}

\begin{enumerate}\belowdisplayskip=0pt \abovedisplayskip=0pt % optional
  \item \mi\begin{align*}\md
      x^2 + y^2 &= x^2 + (iy)^2 \\
              &= (x + iy) (x - iy)
  \end{align*}
  \item \mi\begin{align*}\md
     \frac{1}{n^2-4} &= \frac14 \frac{4}{(n-2)(n+2)} \\
                    &= \frac14 \left( \frac{1}{n-2}-\frac{1}{n+2} \right)
  \end{align*}
  \begin{enumerate}
      \item \mi\[\md x^n + y^n = z^n\]
      \item \mi\[\md \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}\]
      \item \mi
\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\md text & text & text \\
\hline
text & text & text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\end{center}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\section{Automatic version}

\begin{enumerate}\belowdisplayskip=0pt \abovedisplayskip=0pt % optional
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{align*}{%
  \mi\start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne\md
}{%
  \math@cr \black@\totwidth@
  \egroup
  \ifingather@
    \restorealignstate@
    \egroup
    \nonumber
    \ifnum0=`{\fi\iffalse}\fi
  \else
    $$%
  \fi
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\[\expandafter{\expandafter\mi\[\md}
\makeatother
  \item \begin{align*}
      x^2 + y^2 &= x^2 + (iy)^2 \\
              &= (x + iy) (x - iy)
  \end{align*}
  \item \begin{align*}
     \frac{1}{n^2-4} &= \frac14 \frac{4}{(n-2)(n+2)} \\
                    &= \frac14 \left( \frac{1}{n-2}-\frac{1}{n+2} \right)
  \end{align*}
  \begin{enumerate}
      \item \[ x^n + y^n = z^n\]
      \item \[ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}\]
      \item \mi
\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\md text & text & text \\
\hline
text & text & text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\end{center}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, very interesting! One might regard the need of multiple compilations and the limitation to `pdftex` as downsides, but very minor ones, I think. The big plus is the flexibility! Nice!

Comment: Inserting `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` before `\item\mi\begin{flalign*}\md [...] \end{flalign*}` seems necessary to recover the same vertical spacing with what precedes `\item` as when a simple `\item $\displaystyle [...] $` is used.

Answer (score 7):

You can put the numbers as equation tags into the first line of the `align*` environment if you use the `leqno` option: `\tag*{1.}`. If you want to get automatic numbering, the following code can help you:

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{exercisenumber}
\setcounter{exercisenumber}{0}
\newcommand\leftnum{%
    \addtocounter{exercisenumber}{1}%
    \tag*{\phantom{99.}\llap{\arabic{exercisenumber}.}}%
    }
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}\leftnum
  x^2 + y^2 &= x^2 - (iy)^2 \\
            &= (x + iy) (x - iy)
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}\leftnum
  \frac{1}{n^2-4} &= \frac14 \frac{4}{(n-2)(n+2)} \\
                  &= \frac14 \left( \frac{1}{n-2}-\frac{1}{n+2} \right)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Concerning your additional question in the comment: I don't know exactly know what output you're aiming at, but you can try this:

```
\newcounter{exercisenumber}
\newcounter{subnumber}
\setcounter{exercisenumber}{0}
\newcommand\leftnum{%
    \addtocounter{exercisenumber}{1}%
    \tag*{\phantom{99.}\llap{\arabic{exercisenumber}.}}%
    }
\newenvironment{subnumbering}{%
    \addtocounter{exercisenumber}{1}%
    \setcounter{subnumber}{0}
    \renewcommand\leftnum{%
        \addtocounter{subnumber}{1}%
        \tag*{\phantom{99(a)}\llap{%
              \ifnum\value{subnumber}=1 \arabic{exercisenumber}\fi
              (\alph{subnumber})}}%
        }
    }{}
```

Comment: Looks good although I am worried that the numbers will properly line up when there is more than one digit in the number (i.e., the first digit of each number will line up instead of the units digit since the numbers are left-aligned). Also, I'd like to be able to nest `enumerate` environments to get labels like (a), (b), (c) nested within 1., 2., 3. and it's not clear how you could adapt this to work in that case.

Comment: @Ben: The first problem is easily solved; see my edit. (If you have numbers going beyond 99, replace `99` with `999`.) For the second problem I don't have an easy fix. (You didn't really ask for this `:-)`)

Comment: Right, I didn't. But now I am! `;)` (It's fine, this is still a good solution and is the closest to what I'm looking for.)

Comment: @Ben: There you are.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}\belowdisplayskip=0pt \abovedisplayskip=0pt 
  \item \parbox{\linewidth}{\begin{align*}
    x^2 + y^2 &= x^2 + (iy)^2 \\
              &= (x + iy) (x - iy)
  \end{align*}}
  \item 
    \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\begin{align*}
    \frac{1}{n^2-4} &= \frac14 \frac{4}{(n-2)(n+2)} \\
                    &= \frac14 \left( \frac{1}{n-2}-\frac{1}{n+2} \right)
  \end{align*}}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That doesn't really give the desired vertical alignment, does it?

Answer (score 2):

A little variant version of @Herbert.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
   \item  \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{
   \vspace{-2.2em}\begin{align*}
        x^2 + y^2 &= x^2 + (iy)^2 \\
                  &= (x + iy) (x - iy)
   \end{align*}}
   \item \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{
   \vspace{-2.2em}\begin{align*}
        \frac{1}{n^2-4} &= \frac14 \frac{4}{(n-2)(n+2)} \\
                        &= \frac14 \left( \frac{1}{n-2}-\frac{1}{n+2} \right)
   \end{align*}}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks quite good, but the number is not on the baseline of the first line of the `align*` environment: That would need a `\vspace` depending on that first line.

Comment: Looks good but I'd like to avoid the random -2.2em constant because it may vary with different fonts, etc. Any reason you chose that besides trial and error?

Comment: Actually, I prefer a method which is use standard latex command. It is good for every user. 

I think em is mean a point size of your current font so it should be ok in this case. However It should be a better way to define this number.

Comment: @S.Boonto I also use negative `\vspace`, however, it seems more logical to me to use `ex` as the unit instead of `em`, as `ex` is defined as vertical distance (of the letter x) and `em` is defined as horizontal distance (of the capital letter M).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `xparse`. I define new `listalign` and `listgather` environments, which behave as `align` and `gather`, have starred versions, but add no vertical skip at the beginning. They're intended to be used in list environments, if there is no text after an `\item` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{listgather}{s}{%
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\gather\st@rredtrue}{\gather}}%
{\endgather}
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{listalign}{s}{%
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne}{\align}}%
{\endalign}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:cpn {listgather*} {\listgather*}
\cs_new_eq:cN {endlistgather*}\endlistgather
\cs_new:cpn {listalign*} {\listalign*}
\cs_new_eq:cN {endlistalign*}\endlistalign
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text.
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item \begin{listgather}a + b = c + d\end{listgather}
    \item \begin{listgather*}c + d = m + n\end{listgather*}
  \item \begin{listalign*} x^2 + y^2 &= x^2 + (iy)^2 \\
              &= (x + iy) (x - iy)
  \end{listalign*}
  \item \begin{listalign} \frac{1}{n^2-4} &= \frac14 \frac{4}{(n-2)(n+2)} \\
                    &= \frac14 \left( \frac{1}{n-2}-\frac{1}{n+2} \right)
  \end{listalign}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the package `witharrows`. This package provides an environment `{DispWithArrows*}` very similar to `{align*}` (the main difference is that by default, the elements are not composed in displaystyle but this point may be changed with `\WithArrowsOptions`).

By default, `{DispWithArrows*}` has the behaviour required in this question (there is an option `standard-behaviour-with-items` to go back to the behaviour of `{align}`).

Of course, the main goal of `witharrows` was the ability to add arrows. That's why I have added an arrow as example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{witharrows}
\WithArrowsOptions{displaystyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \begin{DispWithArrows*}
    x^2 + y^2 &= x^2 - (iy)^2 \Arrow{factorization} \\
              &= (x + iy) (x - iy)
  \end{DispWithArrows*}
  \item \begin{DispWithArrows*}
    \frac{1}{n^2-4} &= \frac14 \frac{4}{(n-2)(n+2)} \\
                    &= \frac14 \left( \frac{1}{n-2}-\frac{1}{n+2} \right)
  \end{DispWithArrows*}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the code above]