# Environments nested in Lists

Tags: spacing, lists, nesting

I have a list with several items consisting solely of an `align` environment:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{align}
e^{\pi i} + 1 &= 0\\
1 + 1 &= 2
\end{align}
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

By default, the environment begins on the line after the numbering. Other list environments with nested environments also prepend a line break automatically:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item
\[e^{\pi i} + 1 = 0\]
\end{itemize}
```

What is the best method to start the environment on the same line as the numbering?

Comment: Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9394 and the linked questions there.

Comment: Can you explain why you need the enumerate list _without_ text but _with_ aligned equations in each om them? I have a feeling you're looking for the wrong hammer to nail your problem. If the previous sentence doesn't make sense, can you give a _real_ example of what the first two items in your output would look like.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I purposefully kept the question general in case others have the same problem, but here: http://imgur.com/gwVj0. In this case, I'm writing "one-line" solutions to a math test, where each step is self-explanatory. It seems from Philippe's comment that I'm not the only one with this need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to number the equations (and this wouldn't make much sense anyway), then `aligned` is what you're looking for:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item
$\begin{aligned}[t]
e^{\pi i} + 1 &= 0\\
1 + 1 &= 2
\end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
```

The environments `aligned`, `alignedat` and `gathered` can take an optional argument telling LaTeX what vertical alignment we want with respect to the context; it can be `[t]` or `[b]` (default is center alignment), similarly to `tabular`, `array` and `minipage`.

Comment: Neat. I didn't know about the `[t]` option for `aligned`.

Comment: This is what I wanted, thanks. (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9640/11452 lists solutions that work with `align` and so allow numbering and `\displaybreak`, but it was too much effort in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not want really to put an equation into `enumerate`.  What you want is to put equation number on left.  Here is how:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  e^{\pi i} + 1 = 0
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if you really, really want to use `enumerate`, try this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item\leavevmode\par\vspace*{-25pt}%
  \[e^{\pi i} + 1 = 0\]
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the OP  wants to be able to use an `align` to align multiple equations, so each group would be numbered.

Comment: Then he needs `amsmath` with `leqno` option.  Anyway, using `enumerate` for numbering formulas is a bad idea: the spacing will be completely wrong.

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I want; I oversimplified my question. I have multiple groups of equations, in this case solutions to numbered math problems. I actually don't care about numbering formulas, since I rarely reference previous ones.

Comment: ok, see the update

Comment: Upvoted for the nice use of `\leavevmode` to keep it single-line. However, this technique was simply too fragile - I had to make adjustments since it was thrown off by adjusting the font size and even by merely loading the `amsmath` package (?!). It can be made slightly more robust by using `em` instead `pt`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is to use an in-text equation, with `\displaystyle` if necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item This item contains text.
\item \( \displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{j^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}. \)
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the OP  wants to be able to use an `align` to align multiple equations, not just one.

Comment: I took "One item in the enumerate environment consists solely of an equation environment" to imply that the other items contain text.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear - I am typing a list of solutions to a math test. Several items are multi-line and use `align`. There are also several one-line items, but I still prefer \[...\] since `\displaystyle` clogs up the source.

Comment: *That should be `\[...\]`.