# Aligning equations with a label

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment

I just discovered how to use `flalign*` to left justify my multi-line equation, but I would like it to start immediately after the `a) lim...` in my `enumerate` without going to the next line.

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \begin{flalign*}
          L&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n^2-1}&\\
           &=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n^2-1}\frac{(\frac{1}{n^2})}{(\frac{1}{n^2})}‌​\\
           &=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n}{n^2}}{\frac{n^2}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}}\\ 
           &=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}\\
           &=\frac{0}{1-0}\\
           &=0 
        \end{flalign*}
   \item
```

It always goes to the next line. How do I move it up?

Comment: If you are not using a multi-line equation, you should just use `$<eqn>$`, rather than `\begin{flalign*}<eqn>\end{flalign*}`.

Comment: Please show a complete small document that shows what you are trying to do. why enumerate rather than using a numbered math alignment?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Perhaps this question will solve your issue: [Vertical alignment of align* in enumerate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/vertical-alignment-of-align-in-enumerate/).

Comment: I am using a multi-line equation. I would just like this to start with a)  lim... and so on without going to the next line.                           \begin{enumerate}
\item 
\begin{flalign*}
L&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n^2-1}&\\
&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n^2-1}\frac{(\frac{1}{n^2})}{(\frac{1}{n^2})}\\
&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n}{n^2}}{\frac{n^2}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}}\\
&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}\\
&=\frac{0}{1-0}\\
&=0
\end{flalign*}
\item

Comment: The first line in the `flalign*` includes a second `&` - is that intentional?

Comment: As per [Vertical alignment of align* in enumerate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/vertical-alignment-of-align-in-enumerate/), just using `\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
          L&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n^2-1}&\\
           &=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n^2-1}\frac{(\frac{1}{n^2})}{(\frac{1}{n^2})}‌​\\
           &=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n}{n^2}}{\frac{n^2}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}}\\ 
           &=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}\\
           &=\frac{0}{1-0}\\
           &=0 
        \end{aligned}$` seems to work.