# How to align the first line in "align*" to the "item" counter

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[more]{tasks}
\NewTasks[
counter-format={tsk[1])},%%1,a,A,r,R
label-format=\bfseries,
label-width=1.5em,
label-align=left,    %% or right as you wish
label-offset=0.5em,
item-indent=2em,
after-item-skip=0pt,
after-skip=-0.5\baselineskip,
before-skip=0.5\baselineskip,
resume=false         %% comment this for not to resume
]{problems}[\item](4)%% (4)here makes all of them in 4columns


\begin{document}

\begin{problems}(4)
\item
    \begin{align*}
        3x+y &= 7 \\
        2x+y &= 6
    \end{align*}
\item $
    \begin{cases}
        3x+y &= 7 \\
        2x+y &= 6
    \end{cases}
    $
\item $
    \begin{matrix}
        3x+y &= 7 \\
        2x+y &= 6
    \end{matrix}
    $
\end{problems}
\end{document}
```

How do I change this, so that $3x+y=7$ is vertically aligned with 1)?

That is, I'd like to have the first line of the simultaneous equation to be lifted.

[image]

Thank.

Comment: see, if `\item $\begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned}$` helps.

Comment: instead of using `align*`, which is by definition a display structure, use `$ \begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned} $` which is meant to be used as a component, similar to the `cases` and `matrix`.

Comment: As previous commenters have said; see [Vertical alignment of align\* in enumerate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9394) for an example.

Comment: \begin{aligned}[t] solved this!

Comment: Can you complete your code to make it compilable please?

Comment: @cfr Sorry about that. See updated.

Answer (score 2):

```
\item
    $ \begin{aligned}[t]
        2x+y &= 21 \\
         x-y &= 6
    \end{aligned} $
\item
    $ \begin{aligned}[t]
        5x+y &= 28 \\
         x-y &= 2
    \end{aligned} $
```

Solved this!

Simple as that!

[image]