# Align an array to the top inside enumerate

Tags: align, enumerate

I would like to align a system of 2 equations to the top of a label. Without the bracket (which I intend to use as shown in a), using the [t] option seems to work (see b). Can somebody help?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=15,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label=\alph{*}),itemsep=4pt]
\item $\left\{
\begin{array}[t]{rcl}
3x-2y & = & 7\\
x+2y & = & 5    
\end{array}
\right.$
\item $
\begin{array}[t]{rcl}
3x-2y & = & 7\\
x+2y & = & 5    
\end{array}
$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: related and possibly useful, but not duplicate: [Vertical alignment of `align*` in `enumerate`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9394)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, without additional packages, by `\raisebox{-.5\baselineskip}` like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=15,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label=\alph{*}),itemsep=4pt]
\item \raisebox{-.5\baselineskip}{%
$\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
3x-2y & = & 7\\
x +2y & = & 5    
\end{array}\right.
$
}
\item $
\begin{array}[t]{rcl}
3x-2y & = & 7\\
x +2y & = & 5    
\end{array}
$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to do this in case of 3 or more equations (and therefore lines)?

Comment: It is `\raisebox{-(No. lines - 1)/2\baselineskip}` in general. If four lines, for example, it should be `-1.5\baselineskip`.

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward solution with `delarray`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=15,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{delarray}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label=\alph{*}),itemsep=4pt]
\item $
\begin{array}[t]\{{rcl}.
3x-2y & = & 7\\
x+2y & = & 5
\end{array}
$
\item $
\begin{array}[t]{rcl}
3x-2y & = & 7\\
x+2y & = & 5
\end{array}
$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works for me, thank you very much. Any chance to find a solution without an additional package, maybe another environment?