# Avoiding blank row when adding aligned equations with flalign inside enumerate

Tags: enumerate, itemize, alignment, flalign

I need to avoid the blank row in the figure below which is added when I use flalign inside enumerate. How can I overcome this problem?

[image]

```
   \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*\textsuperscript{a}.]
    \item $T_S < T_i < 2 T_S$;
    \item \begin{flalign*}
        C_S &= T_1 - T_S \\
        C_i &= T_{i+1} - T_i \quad \forall i \neq n &&
    \end{flalign*}
    \end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Addressed in this question: [Vertical alignment of `align*` in `enumerate`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9394)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gues, that you looking for something like this:

[image]

This is not possible to achieve by `flalign*` but `aligned` in in-line math mode is promising:

```
\documentclass[rmp,reprint]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*\textsuperscript{a}.]
    \item $T_S < T_i < 2 T_S$;
    \item $\begin{aligned}[t]
        C_S &= T_1 - T_S \\
        C_i &= T_{i+1} - T_i \quad \forall i \neq n &&
    \end{aligned}$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @Zarko thank you very much for your precoius answer.