# Center the text, but not the item number, in an enumerate item

Tags: enumerate, overleaf

So, I'm using LaTeX for my math homework and I'm having trouble with figuring out `enumerate` in Overleaf. Right now what I'm trying to do is write an answer that is centered, but I can't figure out how to do it without centering the question number, which I don't want to do.

Problematic code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{center}
$math$
\end{center}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Is there any way of getting around this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question provides several approaches to this situation: [Vertical alignment of `align*` in `enumerate`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9394) Potential duplicate,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the maths be on the same line as the enumerate number, you can do it with a simple `\makebox`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \begin{document}

    The formula for the solution of the quadratic equation $\,ax^2 + bx + c = 0\,$:
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \makebox[\linewidth]{$x = \dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{{2a}}$}
    \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So this works, but is there any way to control the horizontal spacing the box creates after it? Since it's different from the spacing between other lines

Comment: @tcb93: The only way I can see for thr horizontal spacing is to try adding an `\hspace{some length}`, because by default the content of an `\makebox` is centred in the box.

Answer (score 0):

Use display math (enclose in `\[` and `\]`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \[ math \]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But that creates an empty line which I don't want. Thanks anyways!