# Alignment for equations with numbering in enumeration environment and in environment of cases

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, lists, enumerate

I have problem of alignment in the following, please check and suggest solution:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{equation}
    \kappa_{a,b}(t)=\begin{cases} 
            e^{at}, & 0\leq t<\infty,\\
            e^{bt}, & -\infty<t<0.                              
            \end{cases}
\label{eq:kappa-ab-t}
\end{equation}
\item
\begin{equation}
        \beta(x)=\frac{x^m}{\mu_n^{2k'-1}}
        \label{eq:beta-x}
\end{equation}
    for m=1, 2, 3, \ldots, n=1, 2, 3, \ldots, k'=0, 1, 2, \ldots.
\end{enumerate}
```

In output equations doesn't appear in the same line as of item number, appears at center of second line. I want it to appear in the same line with left alignment and corresponding equation numbers to right of page.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) In its current form, your 'question' doesn't actually ask a question. Please update it with something specific. It would also be best to make your code into a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: Does [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9384/2417) help?

Comment: @ cmhughes I have made some changes to question, hope it will be clear now.

Comment: @ Ian, I checked it. sorry, it is not solving my problem.

Comment: Another suggestion: [Displaying an equation in a list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3109).

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `flalign` environment from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) with the numbers in the first column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{thing}
\setcounter{thing}{0}
\newcommand\leftno{\addtocounter{thing}{1} \arabic{thing}.\quad }
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
\leftno &   \kappa_{a,b}(t)=
  \begin{cases} 
   e^{at}, & 0\leq t<\infty,\\
   e^{bt}, & -\infty<t<0.                              
   \end{cases}
    \label{eq:kappa-ab-t} & \\
\leftno & \beta(x)=\frac{x^m}{\mu_n^{2k'-1}}
        \label{eq:beta-x} & \\
\setcounter{thing}{27} %Test alignment of two digit numbers
\leftno & \beta(x)=\frac{x^m}{\mu_n^{2k'-1}} & 
\end{flalign}
    for m=1, 2, 3, \ldots, n=1, 2, 3, \ldots, k'=0, 1, 2, \ldots.
\end{document}
```

Numbering on both the left- and right-hand sides looks rather strange, though.

Comment: @ Ian, Thanks. This has solved my problem. Its listing of some functions under a chapter which will be referred further in other chapters, so may feel at first strange.